# convert specific workbook in directory from xlsx to txt using excel 2010 vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert all ~200 `xlsx` files `txt` using the below `vba`.  In each `.xlsx` file there is a worksheet with "analysis" in the name that I am trying to copy to `Const Filepath`  So in that directory there will be 200 `txt` files all from the "analysis" sheet in the `.xlsx` files. The `vba` runs but nothing happens and I need some expert help getting this to work.  Thank you :).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim fName As String, fPath As String, wb As Workbook

Const Filepath  As String = "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\folder"

fPath = "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\epilepsy\"
fName = Dir(fPath & "*analysis*.xlsx")
Do While fName <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName)
    wb.SaveAs Left(fName, Len(fName) - 5) & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText
    fName = Dir
    Filename = Filepath & "\" & Left(oFile, InStrRev(oFile, ".")) & "txt"

                Open Filename For Output Access Write As #1
                Print #1, Text
                Close #1
 Loop
 End Sub
```

Comment: You say that the VBA runs but "nothing happens". Well, what exactly does happen? Do you get an error message? Do any of the .xlsx files actually open in the background? Or does literally nothing happen, as if the program skips through the code to the end?

Comment: So it looks like it does run and trys to save a `txt` file in the new directory but it is blank.  Also, it looks like each sheet in the `.xlsx` is being copied not just the specific one.  Thank you :).